# Filtrar por Regex, PYTHON

Tags: python, regex

Quiero filtrar algunas palabras con regex, pero aun no lo entiendo al 100%. Un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer es "filtrar" las palabras de la lista
["Banana", "Chacarero", "Italiano", "Muchas Patatas Fritas", "Among us"], con el requisito de que tengan 3 o más "a".

Ejemplo de lo que trate de hacer:

```
import re

pruebas = ["Banana", "Chacarero", "Italiano", "Muchas Patatas Fritas", "Among us"]

for s in pruebas:
    print(re.match('a{3}\w', s))
    print("")
```

En todos los casos imprime None, cuando me gustaría que solo imprimiese None, en "Chacarero", "Italiano", y "Among us"

Comment: Las expresiones regulares hay que entenderlas como el conjunto de todas las posibles expansiones de la expresión. Tu expresión "a{3}\w" se expande a {"aaax", "aaay", "aaaz", ...} donde \w representa cualquier carácter alfanumérico y a{3} representa tres "a"

Comment: Por que usar expresiones regulares para algo así. Si queres saber la cantidad de a que tiene una cadena, alcanza con candena.count("a"), o mejor, hacer un bucle for que vaya contando las a hasta que se llegue a 3.

Comment: Lo primero es saber cuando ocupar expresiones regulares. En este caso, no se justifica; basta con `s.count('a')` para saber cuantas 'a' tiene la palabra.

Comment: *Quiero filtrar algunas palabras con regex* -> me hace entender que quieres extraer las palabras del array que contengan 3 `a`, y para esto si se utilizaría regex, si no me equivoco. Prueba con la expresión regular `re.search('(.*a){3}', s)`

Answer (score 2):

La expresión que coincide con tu criterio (al menos 3 "a") es:

```
re.match('(.*a){3}', s)
```

y si quieres filtrar, lo que hay que hacer es buscar los resultados nulos.

```
[s for s in pruebas if not re.match('(.*a){3}', s) is None]
```